# How to get text in between two sections?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I want to get text in between START & STOP. Remaining text should be deleted, like `some_text_1` and `some_text_2`.

```
some_text_1
some_text_1
.
.
.
START
---
Values that I want to get
...
STOP
some_text_2
some_text_2
```

From my findings, `sed` does similar job, but only oposite, like:
`sed '/START/,/STOP/d' file` which would give me everything **else** then content in between START & STOP.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invert the sense using `!`

```
sed '/START/,/STOP/!d' file
```

or explicitly print matching lines using `p` in combination with the `-n` command line option

```
sed -n '/START/,/STOP/p' file
```

Comment: Guess I was close :) Accepting in mins. Thank you.